# PHP script that calculates powers that are < X

Tags: php

I have a problem with my PHP script for calculating powers.

```
$A = $_POST["a"]; //Base number
$B = $_POST["b"]; //Value that POW of $A can't exceed. for example if A = 2, B = 1000, then highest solution = 512 

for ($i = 1; $A <= $B; $i++) {
            echo $i . ". ";
            echo pow($A, $i);
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

With the example i mentioned above, i know this script would still display 1024 but the problem is it doesn't work at all. I tried doing this many other ways and nothing works for me... please any guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: As the values for `$A <= $B` are never changed in the loop, then it will never stop.

Comment: @NigelRen OH! that's why it was looping like that... Thank you! I've came up with a solution that works as I suppose it should :) now only need to remove that 1024 somehow

Comment: @NigelRen Got it working completely :) thank you!

Comment: If you want to post it as an answer, it will show what you have done.

Comment: @NigelRen Sorry didn't see that option before! fixed it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the example of `$A = 2; $B = 10;` so you'd expect to get 2, 4, 8.

Your for loop has as condition, execute as long as `$A <= $B`.

**Let us manually do some iterations:**
Run 1: `$A: 2, $B: 10, ($A <= $B): true, $i: 1, output: "1. 2<br>"`
Run 2: `$A: 2, $B: 10, ($A <= $B): true, $i: 2, output: "1. 4<br>"`
Run 3: `$A: 2, $B: 10, ($A <= $B): true, $i: 3, output: "1. 8<br>"`
Run 4: `$A: 2, $B: 10, ($A <= $B): true, $i: 4, output: "1. 16<br>"`
Run 5: `$A: 2, $B: 10, ($A <= $B): true, $i: 5, output: "1. 32<br>"`
Run X: `$A: 2, $B: 10, ($A <= $B): true, $i: X, output: "1. 2^X<br>"`

As we can see, the tested condition `$A <= $B` is always true. How to fix this? One option is to update variable `$A`, like this:

```
$A = $_POST["a"]; //Base number
$B = $_POST["b"]; //Value that POW of $A can't exceed. for example if A = 2, B = 1000, then highest solution = 512 

for ($i = 1; $A <= $B; $i++) {
    $A = pow($A, $i);
    if ($A <= $B) {
        echo $i . ". ";
        echo $A;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use a break condition:

```
$A = $_POST["a"]; //Base number
$B = $_POST["b"]; //Value that POW of $A can't exceed. for example if A = 2, B = 1000, then highest solution = 512 

for ($i = 1; true; $i++) {
    $A = pow($A, $i);
    if ($A > $B) {
        break;
    }
    echo $i . ". ";
    echo $A;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

This is an infinite loop, which usually gets written as

```
$A = $_POST["a"]; //Base number
$B = $_POST["b"]; //Value that POW of $A can't exceed. for example if A = 2, B = 1000, then highest solution = 512 

$i = 1;
while (true) {
    if ($A > $B) {
        break;
    }
    echo $i . ". ";
    $A = pow($A, $i);
    echo $A;
    echo '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

One last thing, since `$A` and `$B` get submitted by a client, you shouldn't assume they're numbers. You can simply cast them to numbers using:

```
$A = (int) $_POST['a'];
$B = (int) $_POST['b'];
```

How I personally would write that code:

```
// get variables
$base = (int) $_POST["a"];
$max = (int) $_POST["b"];

// validate input
if ($max < $base) {
    echo 'error: Max number bigger than base number!<br>';
} elseif ($base < 2) {
    echo 'error: Base number needs to be >= 2!<br>';
}

/** SOLUTION 1 - using `pow` */
// starting exponent
$exp = 1;
// assign $base^$exp to $result and test it against $max
while (($result = pow($base, $exp)) <= $max) {
    // echo current row
    echo $exp.'. '.$result.'<br>';
    // increment exponent
    $exp++;
}

/** SOLUTION 2 - using dynamic programming instead of calling `pow` in each iteration */
// multiply $result with the base and check against $max
for ($result = 1, $exp = 1; ($result *= $base) <= $max; $exp++) {
    echo $exp.'. '.$result.'<br>';
}

/** In case you don't need the exponent:
for ($result = 1; ($result *= $base) <= $max;) {
    echo $result.'<br>';
}
*/
```

Try to pick variables that explain what they're doing and add comments to explain what's happening.

Comment: I figured it out myself as well but WOW, Thank you for that step by step tutorial!!! And right... there's no need for $C like in my version, i could just update the $A. Thank you again :) Didn't expect an answer like that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$C = 1;
for ($i = 1; $C <= $B; $i++) {
            $C = pow($A, $i);
            if ($C <= $B) {
                echo $i . ". " . $C . '<br>';
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Just added a variable $C that changes each time the loop runs so it can actually finish.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].